# How do I prefix a gmake variable

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a Makefile that includes another makefile, say CommonMakefile. There is a variable that I want to prefix with a value (*cf.* appending using `+=`) keeping rest of the value intact.

```
V = value1    # set in CommonMakefile that is included

V = value0 $(V)  # I want to prefix value0 to V

# rule defined in CommonMakefile that is included
whatsV:
     echo $V   # first char is a <TAB> here
```

How can I do that?

Expecting:

```
$ gmake whatsV
value0 value1
```

Actual:

```
$ gmake whatsV
Makefile:3: *** Recursive variable `V' references itself (eventually).  Stop.
```

PS: I can-not/do-not-want to change CommonMakefile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work:

```
V = value0 $(V)
```

because here `V` is a [*recursively expanded variable*](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Flavors), and it can't be defined in terms of itself. But change it to a *simply expanded variable*:

```
V := value0 $(V) # <-- Note the colon
```

and it will work as intended.

Comment: Thanks @Beta for the answer and link. Also, from the link, the section [Reading Makefiles](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Reading-Makefiles) has a note saying: For the append operator, ‘+=’, the right-hand side is considered immediate if the variable was previously set as a simple variable (‘:=’), and deferred otherwise.